# No type arguments expected for interface Callback

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit2

I'm a mid-Senior level Android developer who is working on some projects to upgrade my skills. While developing one of my projects. I came across the following error:

```
C:\Users\animesh.vashistha\StudioProjects\MovieListApp\app\src\main\java\com\example\movielistapp\MainViewModel.kt: (21, 43): No type arguments expected for interface Callback
```

My MainViewModel looks like this:

```
package com.example.movielistapp

import android.graphics.Movie
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.example.movielistapp.data.MainRepository
import com.example.movielistapp.model.Model
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Response
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback

class MainViewModel constructor(private val repository: MainRepository)  : ViewModel() {

    val movieList = MutableLiveData<List<Model.Movie>>()
    val errorMessage = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun getAllMovies() {

        val response = repository.getAllMovies()
        response.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Movie>>{
            fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Model.Movie>>, response: Response<List<Model.Movie>>) {
                movieList.postValue(response.body())
            }

            fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Model.Movie>>, t: Throwable) {
                errorMessage.postValue(t.message)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I have imported import retrofit2.call as answered in other solutions to this question. Can someone please check and tell what wrong I'm doing?

Comment: this should be `Callback<List<Movie>>` -> `Callback<List<Model.Movie>>` .  you have imported the wrong `Movie` class check the import .

Comment: checked and corrected the imports...still getting same error on response.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Model.Movie>>{

Comment: Did you fix this incorrect import? `javax.security.auth.callback.Callback`

Comment: Thanks @Tenfour04 for correction. A silly mistake it was :)